# ShareIntent won't update value from textView

Tags: android, random, textview, swipe

I am trying to write an app where I utilize a swipe functionality. Everytime the user swipes the phone, a random number is generated and the number is used to get the string value within the array, myNames[], and displayed on textView. I want to share using line or any text messaging app the value displayed on textView. My ultimate question is :Why doesn't the shareIntent recognize the textView.getText().toString(); and enable sharing of that string value? I've been trying to figure this out for days and couldn't figure out why it won't update the value everytime a swipe is initiated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
float x1, x2;
float y1, y2;
SharedPreferences preferences;
ShareActionProvider provider;
TextView textView;
String z;
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

final String myNames[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/example.ttf");

    textView.setTypeface(font);

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    Random randGen = new Random();
    int rando =randGen.nextInt(myNames.length);

    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

    // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        x1 = touchevent.getX();
        y1 = touchevent.getY();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        x2 = touchevent.getX();
        y2 = touchevent.getY();

        if (x1 < x2) {

            textView.setText(myNames[rando]);

        }

        // if right to left sweep event on screen
        if (x1 > x2) {
            textView.setText(myNames[rando]);
        }
    }
    }z=myNames[rando];

    return false;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    String y="yolo";

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem
            .getActionProvider();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to sahre test: " + textView.getText().toString()
            );

    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` only runs once - when the menu is initially created.

You should instead save a reference to your `ShareActionProvider` and call `setShareIntent()` every time your `TextView`'s text changes (i.e., as part of your `ACTION_UP`).

Comment: I understand the onCreateOptionsMenu and how it only runs once now. I thought I understand the reference to ShareActionProvider and call setShareIntent() in the ACTION_UP but Im getting errors and now im unsure how it is to be done. Is this along the lines of what's supposed to be done?                                                                                                     `if (x1 < x2) {    
textView.setText(myNames[rando]); mShare.setShareIntent(textView.getText().toString());
}`

Comment: You need to do all of the lines needed to build the share Intent: basically move all of the logic you have in onCreateOptionsMenu over

Comment: Wow thank you very much. It worked well. Just out of curiosity, this particular swipe functionality, does it allow for only left and right swiping with the trail? The trail as in the numbers don't just appear but slide gracefully from 1 to 2?

Comment: That definitely a different question, but TextView has no inherent way of changing how the text is updated: it just replaces it.

Comment: If this helped answer your question, please make sure to accept it to remove it from the list of unanswered questions